# UITableView reload sections crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata, nsindexset

I'm using `[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:k] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];`, I examined I'm getting a valid value for k but still I'm getting `-[NSIndexSet initWithIndexesInRange:]: Range {9223372036854775807, 1} exceeds maximum index value of NSNotFound - 1`.

Answer (score -1):

**Try following code it may help you**

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
NSIndexSet *section = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];                                     
[self.tableView reloadSections:section withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying but, I'm wondering the code remains the same can you explain why this will work.

Comment: Before giving negative rate and wear spec and read I just say tried it read bold text and i am not say that it will workd.